# What happen Http Status 500 Error instantiating servlet class

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class SAA.Servlet.Addrest
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SAA.Servlet.Addrest
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What do you think is the meaning of this? `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SAA.Servlet.Addrest `

Comment: Check your web.xml paths of servlet class.

Comment: Try `jar tvvf <mywarfile>.war` Also, I suspect, "Addrest" should be "Address"

Answer (score 1):

It is not able to find `SAA.Servlet.Addrest` in your classpath

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SAA.Servlet.Addrest
```

- Make sure fully qualified class name is correct
- Make sure class is in classpath with fully qualified package space

Comment: How do you `Make sure fully qualified class name is correct`?